# Rails 3: Migrate data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, data-migration

My Rails 3 app has a User model and a Profile model. A User `has_one` Profile.

Currently the Profile has attributes `first_name` and `last_name`. While I'm not sure why you might want to change them, I originally imagined these should be changeable and so I put them in the Profile model instead of the User model.

However, as the app has evolved I have found that in fact I need the user's first and last name not to be changed, and that I really need them to be part of the User model instead of the profile model.

So, I was wondering, can you write a migration that would:

1. Add the `first_name` and `last_name` columns to the User model.
2. Take the existing `first_name` and `last_name` value for a given user from the associated Profile record and copy it into the User model.
3. Remove the `first_name` and `last_name` columns from the Profile model since they wouldn't be needed anymore.

So, can this be done? Could you show an example? And, most importantly, are there any gotchas I should be aware of? I'd like to apply this change to a production app so it's critical that I don't lose data when I make this change.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit curious why the `User` model would not allow these attributes to be changed, while the `Profile` model would. There really shouldn't be a different in these cases unless you've explicitly specified which attributes are accessible anyways.

Comment: Oh they both can allow or not allow changes -- I just have grouped things in the user model to be "permanent" (ie I don't let the user change them) and things in the profile to all be "non-permanent" (ie I allow the user to change them). But I find that I increasingly need to use the users first and last name as part of file identifiers etc that really can't be changed, so to me I'd rather now group it with the more static user attributes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, very easy. Put this in a migration:

```
    add_column(:users, :last_name, :string)
    add_column(:users, :first_name, :string)

    User.reset_column_information

    User.all.each do |u|
      u.last_name = u.profile.try(:last_name)
      u.first_name = u.profile.try(:first_name)
      u.save
    end

    remove_column(:profiles, :first_name)
    remove_column(:profiles, :last_name)
```

I used try() there to mitigate against the possibility of a missing profile.  It's not checking for errors on the save operation, so take that into account if you think it needs to.  Also, as always, do a database dump backup before you run it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the gem you need :

https://github.com/btelles/legacy_migrations

Comment: Thanks @SpyrosP! That looks promising...did not know of that gem!

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've created a gem which solves the problem with writing migration data in the migrations - https://github.com/ka8725/migration_data.